# Set Keystroke for Service from Terminal

Tags: keyboard, terminal, command-line, services

I created some services to be used in Finder. Now I wanted to create some keystrokes to call these services. That would be easy in the System Settings, however, I would like to add them from the command line in order to automate this setup.

I tried the following which did allow me not trigger the services by a keystroke:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder NSUserKeyEquivalents '{ "label-red" = "$@1"; "label-green" = "$@2"; "label-none" = "$@0"; }'
```

Any ideas to make this work? Instead of `com.apple.Finder` I might have to use another identifier, but which?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PlistBuddy` and `defaults`:

`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Delete NSServicesStatus:"(null) - test2 - runWorkflowAsService"' ~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist 2>/dev/null;defaults write pbs NSServicesStatus -dict-add '"(null) - test2 - runWorkflowAsService"' '{key_equivalent = "^~@2";}'`

The `PlistBuddy` command is not needed if there is not an existing entry for the service. Replace `test2` with the name of the service. Quit and reopen applications to apply the changes.

`^~@2` is control-option-command-2. See https://web.archive.org/web/20161220060333/http://osxnotes.net/keybindings.html.