# Where are keyboard shortcuts stored (for backup and sync purposes)?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

Where can I access OS X keyboard shortcuts, say for Dropbox sync?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The shortcuts that can be set in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts are stored in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` and the property lists of applications (like `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunes.plist` or `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.chess/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.chess.plist`).

The shortcuts for services are stored in [~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79626/set-keystroke-for-service-from-terminal/79663#79663).

Comment: I wonder if I'm the only person this didn't work for. These files also don't seem to be the XML files that I'd expect - they seem to have some binary or something...

Comment: same, don't work for me (macOS Sierra 10.12.2)

Comment: This appeared as binary for me as well. But then use the command `plutil -convert xml1 .GlobalPreferences.plist` to convert it to XML, and `plutil -convert binary1 .GlobalPreferences.plist` to convert it back. Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1768480?tstart=0

Comment: Also, TextWrangler can open binary plist files.

Comment: You can use https://apps.apple.com/us/app/plist-editor/id1157491961?mt=12 to edit the file easily (binary) but I also don't see keyboard shortcuts in this file...

Comment: Looking at http://aubrey.pw/d/2020/1602692656.png it looks like the shortcuts for each app is actually stored in their own respective `.plist` file. But, maybe global shortcuts are stored in `.Globa...` file.

Comment: My last comment is maybe false, as I found the keyboard shortcut e.g. for Harvest was in `~/Library/Preferences/com.getharvest.harvestxapp.plist` - http://aubrey.pw/d/2020/1602693929.png

Comment: Also you can use `sudo opensnoop | grep '.plist'` while editing shortcuts to see what `.plist` files have been modified.

Comment: I found out that as of Catalina an app section in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts has to be created first. Otherwise, the system doesn't see the shortcuts defined in .plist (e.g. copied over from elsewhere). Once you create a section e.g. with a dummy shortcut, the .plist can be copied over and it takes effect fine.

Answer (score 11):

As described in the accepted answer, you can determine an app's shortcuts by converting the plist to xml and then parsing the xml. You can also (tested on macOS Sierra 10.12.6) get the values directly with the `defaults read` command.

To write out the user key commands that apply in all applications run `defaults read NSGlobalDomain NSUserKeyEquivalents`:

```
$ defaults read NSGlobalDomain NSUserKeyEquivalents
{
    "Enter Full Screen" = "@^f";
    "Exit Full Screen" = "@^f";
    "Merge All Windows" = "@$m";
}
```

To write out the user keyboard shortcuts for a particular app, use `defaults read <app-plist-name> NSUserKeyEquivalents`. For example, to get the user keyboard shortcuts for Safari run (in this example, the user hasn't set any custom keyboard shortcuts for Safari)

```
$ defaults read com.apple.safari NSUserKeyEquivalents
The domain/default pair of (com.apple.safari, NSUserKeyEquivalents) does not exist
```

Key mappings I have discovered in this string syntax:

- `command` = `@`
- `control` = `^`
- `option` = `~`
- `shift` = `$`

Comment: For global shortcuts, you can also use `defaults read -g NSUserKeyEquivalents`

Comment: is there a `defaults write` command to similarly set keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: My experiment told me that it should be `@` for `command` and `$` for shift.

Answer (score 3):

This command will print the keyboard shortcuts along with the prefix required  to set them:

```sh
printf "defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSUserKeyEquivalents '$(defaults read NSGlobalDomain NSUserKeyEquivalents)'"
```

For an app like Safari, run:

```sh
printf "defaults write -app Safari NSUserKeyEquivalents '$(defaults read -app Safari NSUserKeyEquivalents)'"
```

Those commands will output something like: `defaults write [...] NSUserKeyEquivalents '{...}'`, which can then be used in a shell script

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about later OS versions but on **macOS 10.13 High Sierra** (and recognised from earlier versions), apart from what the [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87619/where-are-keyboard-shortcuts-stored-for-backup-and-sync-purposes#87647) says and likely needed after [neovr's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87619/where-are-keyboard-shortcuts-stored-for-backup-and-sync-purposes#445233), there's also the `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist` key `com.apple.custommenu.apps` used by ***System Preferences***'s user interface **to show applications** with set shortcuts.

---

I had an application that had modified shortcuts but it wasn't showing in *System Preferences*'s user interface (because I had copied the app plist from a backup into `~/Library/Preferences`), so I did following.
Type any command line code on your keyboard or copy and paste it after starting `bash` in *Terminal* (actually I'm using *iTerm*). Hit the return or enter key on your keyboard after any `;` (semicolon).

1. Quit *System Preferences*
2. Store a *CFBundleIdentifier*

   - If you know the CFBundleIdentifier you can type it in or paste it after `CFBundleIdentifier=` and hit enter or return on your keyboard.
   - Otherwise:

     1. Store a *pathToTheApplication*.

        You can type the filesystem path after `pathToTheApplication=/` using your keyboard, optionally completing partial paths with one or two hits on the tab key,
        or by other means:

        1. `pathToTheApplication=` - don't type return or enter on your keyboard yet.
        2. Drag and drop the application from the *Finder* into the *Terminal*.
        3. Type return or enter on your keyboard.
     2. `CFBundleIdentifier=$(defaults read "$pathToTheApplication"/Contents/Info CFBundleIdentifier);`
3. `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :com.apple.custommenu.apps: string \"$CFBundleIdentifier\"" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist;` - I made a backup copy of the plist first cause I haven't got a working TimeMachine.
4. `killall cfprefsd;` - this will restart a background daemon, updating any changed preferences plists from the filesystem.
5. Open *System Preferences*

---

Other useful command lines:

- To see the current list of applications used in the *System Preferences*'s user interface:
  `defaults read com.apple.universalaccess com.apple.custommenu.apps`
- To find other apps having keyboard shortcuts set:
  `defaults find NSUserKeyEquivalents`