# shortcut alt+cmd+m is blocked

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I use IntelliJ IDEA and the shortcut I am using to "extract a method" seems to be blocked by another application. The shortcut itself is mapped by IntelliJ IDEA.

OS X: 10.10.2, MacBook Pro with english keyboad (and layout)
the shortcut: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>

When I press this combination nothing happens, no other app is reacting either.

I already unchecked all shortcuts in the system preferences that could block IntelliJ IDEA shortcuts. I also quit almost all running applications, no success.

Is there a way to find which program could be blocking this shortcut. I am pretty good with the shell in case there is some find/grep stuff to make this happen.

Comment: check this http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87647/46541

Comment: i will give this a try and post the results. thanks.

Comment: i found the program that was blocking the shortcut. i restarted and closed all apps. the i started one by one and found the app. thanks guys.

Comment: which one was it ?

Comment: it was divvy which i use to maximize windows. so my fault as i chose this shortcut a while ago .... shame on me.

Comment: Nice, now you can formulate that s a answer and we can close the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was divvy which i use to maximize windows. so my fault as i chose this shortcut a while ago .... shame on me.

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to be an easy one to work around -
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>M</kbd>  is the system-wide shortcut for "Hide all windows of the frontmost app"

It would probably be easier to remap to something else for intellij using
Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts

Comment: thanks for your answer. when i use this shortcut nothing happens. the main application is not hidden. the same shortcut works on all other machines for other developers as shortcut inside of intellij. so something must have captured this key on my machine.