# How do I import my OSX Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard

After a clean OS install, is there any way to recover my OS Keyboard Shortcuts from a backup of my previous `User` folder?

Is is somewhere in `Library/Preferences`?

I tried copying `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` (based on another thread here) but that did not seem to work.

(I'm referring to various shortcuts set up in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, particularly > 'App Shortcuts')

Comment: not true, see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Where are keyboard shortcuts stored (for backup and sync purposes)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87619/where-are-keyboard-shortcuts-stored-for-backup-and-sync-purposes) which mentions some relevant files in `~/Library`.

(Also helpful: [Globally edit all keyboard shortcut settings](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040322141804767)  – which talks about manually adding/editing shortcuts.)

Copying `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` from my old account worked, however, I had to log out and do it from a separate account, otherwise OSX will undo any changes to the file.