# How to sync keyboard shortcuts setting of Mac OS X from one computer to another?

Tags: mac, shortcut, git

I have two Macbooks, and I set up many keyboard shortcuts for different applications.

[image: Keyboard shortcuts]

Now I am trying to sync these settings from one Macbook to another through git, which introduced by Atlassian.

https://developer.atlassian.com/blog/2016/02/best-way-to-store-dotfiles-git-bare-repo/

My questions

1. Is there a config file for keyboard shortcuts?
2. Where is it located?
3. Is it easy to add to a git repo?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87619/where-are-keyboard-shortcuts-stored-for-backup-and-sync-purposes