# Share Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: mac, keyboard, shortcut, system-settings

I have about over 100 keyboard shortcuts for my mac, and I want to transfer all those shortcuts to my second computer. Is there a way to do this easily?

Answer (score 1):

The best bet is to change some shortcuts while observing the content of your Preferences folder sorted by modification date.

In my system (10.7.5 Lion) the relevant files are *com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist*, *com.apple.universalaccess.plist* and *pbs.plist* as well as probably somehow related plists like *com.apple.systempreferences.plist*/*com.apple.ServicesMenu.Services.plist*.

If both of your Macs have the same system/apps installed simply copy the files you found.

Answer (score -1):

Unless this is included in a Time Machine backup (in which case you could restore it with Migration Assistant), then not easily.

See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87619/where-are-keyboard-shortcuts-stored-for-backup-and-sync-purposes/87647#87647) and [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/670584/how-can-i-migrate-all-keyboard-shortcuts-from-one-mac-to-another).

> The shortcuts that can be set in System Preferences > Keyboard >
>   Keyboard Shortcuts > Application Shortcuts are stored in
>   `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` and the property lists
>   of applications (like `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunes.plist` or
>   `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.chess/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.chess.plist`).
>
> The shortcuts for services are stored in
>   [`~/Library/Preferences/pbs.plist`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79626/set-keystroke-for-service-from-terminal/79663#79663).